# retrieve email using PHP and pop3 - what is your technique?

Tags: php, pop3

I can see some options available:

1) Use PEAR's POP3 class --> tried it, having some weird weird issues like FF choking to death on their sample code!!!

2) Use PHPClasses ([here](http://www.phpclasses.org/)) --> seems to be the viable option at the time, still working on it

3) Write my own or use one of the snippets available

The target is currently Gmail, but I would like this to work on my ISP mail too (not necessarily same code of course).

What do you use? Pointers to working snippets would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I use the PHPClasses version. Works fine for me - I've been working on an AJAX mail client (personal project, learning exercise really). I also found that the sample code they provided was quite good so you should be able to get something working with it.

Answer (score 9):

The native PHP IMAP functions support POP3 mailboxes, and will probably be faster than anything written purely in PHP. There are generally some useful comments and examples in the PHP manual, for example on the [imap_open](https://www.php.net/imap_open) page.

Answer (score 0):

I've just discovered [ezcomponents](http://ezcomponents.org). Real nice to work with.