# Check email with php

Tags: php, html, email, smtp, pop3

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [retrieve email using PHP and pop3 - what is your technique?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/325579/retrieve-email-using-php-and-pop3-what-is-your-technique)

I was wondering if it is possible to check the email of an account through php. My hosting provider gives me the server address and I know the account information, how can PHP retrieve the emails and display them. All I need is the most basic form. Also I believe that it is a pop3 if that matters.

Thank you so much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I use PHP imap with [imap_open](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.imap-open.php). You will find the doc [here](http://php.net/manual/en/book.imap.php)

Simple usage:

```
$stream = imap_open ("{localhost:110/pop3}INBOX", "user_id", "password");
$mbox = imap_check($stream);
$msg_amount = $mbox->Nmsgs;
```

It is easy to use and works good but it will getting slow if you try to fetch 5000+ mails.
Alternative you can use [fsockopen](http://php.net/manual/en/function.fsockopen.php).

Edit:
To install:

> To get these functions to work, you have to compile PHP with
>   --with-imap[=DIR] , where DIR is the c-client install prefix. From our
>   example above, you would use --with-imap=/usr/local/imap-2000b . This
>   location depends on where you created this directory according to the
>   description above. Windows users may include the php_imap.dll DLL in
>   php.ini. IMAP is not supported on systems earlier than Windows 2000.
>   This is because it uses encryption functions in order to enable SSL
>   connections to the mail servers.

Comment: Im getting this error ....Fatal error: Call to undefined function imap_open()

Comment: add you the how to install. But remember: The IMAP, recode, YAZ and Cyrus extensions cannot be used in conjuction