# Login to Gmail account in a thirdparty application

Tags: javascript, gmail

Is it possible to create an application that would allow the user to login to gmail without redirecting to the site.

Comment: Take a look here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/325579/retrieve-email-using-php-and-pop3-what-is-your-technique

Comment: thanks for the info, but sorry for the wrong tag. If possible I want the application does not include a php script.